# Required request parameter 'searchQuery' for method parameter type String is not present]

Tags: java, spring, vue.js

I am trying to write a search function, but I encounter a bug when I pass the search query from frontend to backend. I tried most of the solution on Internet but it's still not ok.

Complete Error log

> 2022-10-12 15:05:10.575  WARN 21272 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'searchQuery' for method parameter type String is not present]

frontend

```
<template>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="search" class="form-control rounded" v-model="searchQuery" placeholder="Company name" aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="search-addon" />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" @click='searchRecord'>Search</button>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    name: 'RegistrationEnquiry',
    components: {

    },
    data() {
        return {
            records: [],
            searchQuery: '',
        };
    },
    computed: {},
    methods: {
        searchRecord(){
            axios.post('searchRecord', this.searchQuery)
            .then(successResponse => {
                console.log(successResponse)
                })
                .catch(failResponse => {
                    alert("Error(failResponse)")
                    console.log(failResponse)
                })

        },
    },
}

</script>
```

SearchRecordController.java

```
@Controller
public class SearchRecordController {
    @Autowired
    SearchRecordService searchRecordService;

    @CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping(value = "api/searchRecord")
    @ResponseBody
    public String searchRecord(@RequestParam(value = "searchQuery") String searchQuery) {
        System.out.println(searchQuery);
        return searchRecordService.searchRecordService(searchQuery);
    }
}
```

Comment: In `axios.post('searchRecord', this.searchQuery)`, what is `this.searchQuery`?

Comment: your request parameter is null right now, which means nothing is going inside parameter from the page .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the correct way of sending parameters through axios.
You can send params by changing your code in frontend to :-

```
axios.post(`api/searchRecord`, null, { params: {
  searchQuery
}}
```

Which will send the request as :
https://localhost:8080/api/searchRecord?searchQuery=valueofsearchtext

Keep your controller as it is as there are no changes required in the backend.

```
@CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping(value = "api/searchRecord")
    @ResponseBody
    public String searchRecord(@RequestParam(value = "searchQuery") String searchQuery) {
        System.out.println(searchQuery);
        return searchRecordService.searchRecordService(searchQuery);
    }
```

this should sort the issue in your code.

Comment: It raise this error on my console now: POST http://localhost:8090/api/searchRecord?searchQuery=asd 500 AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code: "ERR_BAD_RESPONSE"

Comment: I change the data to searchQuery: JSON.stringify(this.searchQuery) and it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From backend side it seems ok, I think you need to send data in post like that:

```
     searchRecord(){
        axios.post({
           method: 'post',
          url: '/api/searchRecord',
          data: {
           searchQuery: this.searchQuery
          }
        })
        .then(successResponse => {
            console.log(successResponse)
            })
            .catch(failResponse => {
                alert("Error(failResponse)")
                console.log(failResponse)
            })

    }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post.

Answer (score -1):

Front end is not sending data to the controller. Try giving default value=null;

Answer (score -1):

basically, it appears when you send no value from the front end but your controller expects some parameter from the frontend side,
to avoid this u can use "required = false" or u can fix a default value based on your requirement to check where you are going wrong.

```
public String searchRecord(@RequestParam(value = "searchQuery",required = false,defaultValue = "") String searchQuery) {
        return searchRecordService.searchRecordService(searchQuery);
    }
```